# Need Excel function to write repeating numbers of different lengths i.e 1,2,3 - 1,2 - 1,2,3,4

Tags: excel, sequence, repeat

I am struggling to find a way to write repeating number sequences (of different length) down the column. The sequences will range from 1 to 4 numbers long i.e 1,2 or 1,2,3 or 1,2 and so on. The repeating will start at the beginning of a new merged cell in column A. Please see photos.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQBgi.jpg)
[What I need to replicate for thousands of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BswPd.jpg)

Any info helps, thank you!

Comment: Something like: `IF(A2<>"",1,B1+1)`?

Comment: This worked! I dont understand how but I knowit works. Thank you

Comment: Excel recognizes merged rows as a group of cells with only the initial (top) cell containing a value. Hence in your example, cell `A4`=`US` while `A5` is blank. The formula just checks if there's a value in A; if there is, it sets it to 1, if not, it increments the above value by one. Not too complex once you recognize the merged cell behavior.